# C# Assert.AreEqual with multiple validations

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm slightly confused.  I'm writing a test which needs multiple validations to occur. So for example i need to confirm the data is correct, the status of my item and the measure name. For this to happen can i use `Assert.AreEqual` with if statements?

I've pasted my method below.

```
public void validateInventoryMeasurement(string Data, string itemStatus)
{
   var actual = 
   var expected =

   Assert.AreEqual(, actual);
   Console.WriteLine("Assertion pass");
}
```

Comment: So you want to ensure two objects contain the same values? On every property or just some of them?

Comment: It is really unclear what you're asking!

Comment: @Liam Yep correct, so there will be multiple values i'll be looking to validate against

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "multiple validations"? If you could provide a *concrete* example of the expected value, values that you'd expect to pass and values that you'd expect to fail, it'll be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @DaisyShipton By multiple validations i mean, for my actual i will get a linux file which will contain data such as 22,33,555. So that will be one validation occurring. I want to also validate the measure name is correct so for example 'xxxxx.csv.ovr' the name of the file will be the measure name.

Comment: @JOpenDock: Edit your question

Comment: It's also unclear where those two pieces of validation (one for the data, one for the name) would come from. If you want to perform two checks, you need two calls to `Assert.AreEqual` - you'd have two expected values, and two actual values...

Comment: I'm still not clear what your asking

Comment: @DaisyShipton Measure name would be a linux file and the data would be within this file. Which would mean two validations

Comment: Right, so you'd need to perform two assertions, because they'd be asserting different things. Each `Assert.AreEqual` call is going to be checking *one* thing.

Comment: @DaisyShipton So i'd have a var for my expected and actual result right. I understand what i'd put in my 'var expected' but in my 'var actual' how can i define this so it looks at the value from the linux file

Comment: @JOpenDock: You'd read from the file the same way you do elsewhere in code. (`File.ReadAllText`, maybe.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking whether you can use `Assert.AreEqual()` more than once in a single test.  The answer is that you definitely can; whether you should or not is another matter:

```
public void validateInventoryMeasurement(string Data, string itemStatus)
{
    // Arrange
    var expected = 10;
    int anotherValue = 0;

    // Act
    var actual = Calculatevalue(ref anotherValue);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); // Will trigger the unit test to fail if the assertion is not met
    Assert.AreEqual(5, anotherValue); // Will trigger the unit test to fail, assuming that the above condition is met
 }
```

If you need to do this, then there may be a better way to structure your code so that you can have a single action and a single assertion, which IMHO makes for a cleaner and easier to read test.

Based on further comments, what you're looking for may be the `TestCase` decorator.  This allows you to create a single piece of code that's executed once for each variable defined in a `TestCase`.  For example:

```
[TestCase("data1","status1", "valid")]
[TestCase("data2","status2", "invalid")]
[TestCase("data3","status3", "valid")]
[TestCase("data1","status1", "valid")]
public void validateInventoryMeasurement(string Data, string itemStatus, string expectedresult)
{
    // Arrange
    var expected = expectedresult;

    // Act
    var actual = Calculatevalue();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! can i still use the above but include if statements so there is further validations that can occur. So for example expected 10 would be one validation and measure expected xxxx,xxxx,xxxx be the second validation

Comment: @JOpenDock: don't clarify questions in comments to answers but in your question

Comment: I've amended my answer - I think what you're looking for is the `TestCase` decorator

Comment: @pm_2 So just to clarify. Within the Testcase i can pass multiple validations that i need to then one piece of code will run to validate the multiple validations i have in place?

Comment: @bommelding Yep not a unit test. I'm running an automation test to test functionality

Comment: @JOpenDock Yes, the values that you pass correspond to the parameters of the method.